# Fix status bar position

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, iqkeyboardmanager

I added a status bar background view from app delegate with the following code:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.window!.rootViewController!.view.addSubview(view)`
```

The problem starts when I use `IQKeyboardManager`, it slides up that added status bar background view when a text field is pressed. It appears like this:

[image: slid up background view]

How would I fix that status bar position?

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the frame statically. Get the actual frame of the status bar:

```
UIView(frame: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame).
```

Comment: according to your suggestion i set view frame like this           let view = UIView(frame: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.standardized)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.window!.rootViewController!.view.addSubview(view) and added that subview to rootviewcontroller but it's not working